# Probability of losing all the games

Tags: probability, inclusion-exclusion

There are 4 players each have the same probability of winning a game which is 1/4. The 4 players play 7 games, what is the probability that Player i will lose all 7 games?

How would one go about solving this? Would.the answer be 3^7/4^7? Or is it a summation equation?

Comment: I don't see how it is possible that given $4$ players, they play each other and end up with the same number of games played that is not a multiple of $3$. If this happens, then $4*7$ should be a multiple of $6$, which it is not. So I don't know how these people played. It may be possible that they all played once with each other, so  that each played $3$ games and in total $6$ games were played.

Comment: I think it's a four-player game. Maybe they're playing seven games of Monopoly. But the question is open to two interpretations – are you asking for the probably that the player named George loses all seven games? or are you asking for the probability that there is at least one player who loses all seven games?

Comment: The probability of player i will lose all seven games

Answer (score 1):

Your intuition is correct.  It's just the probability of losing one game (3/4) raised to the power of 7.